# Sublime Text: Keyboard shortcut for close all other tabs?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, tabs, sublime-text-2

If you right-click a tab name you have three options for closing:

- Close
- Close others
- Close tabs to the right

If you go through the default shortcuts you'd see only the first is possible using the keyboard.

How could you close the other tabs or tabs to the right using the keyboard?

Is there a built-in command which you can bind keys to?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it yourself
on windows
Preferences - Key bindings default -
add this line and test it ;)

```
[
{ "keys": "alt+w", "command": "close_all" }
]
```

good luck

Comment: I want something to close all other tabs. Not all tabs. The same functionality which is available from the context menu on the tab.

Comment: This was more useful to me than "close other tabs"!

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked before and the accepted answer works. I'm using it myself.:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15379860/close-others-command-shortcut-in-sublime-text-2

It basically says there isn't a native way for users to set it up on sublime. Users have to create a plugin (`Tools/New Plugin`) in order to achieve this. Then manually input the keybindings on the `Keybindings - User` under the `Preferences` menu.